# Call activity in method onPostExecute from asynctask class

Tags: java, php, android

I have problems using the method from the title.
On my android app project i wanna use this method for launching a new activity when I receive a successful message from an .php script. The message is correctly received from the php script but i can't launch the new activity on method onPostExecute no matter what i have tried. 
This is how it look my code, can someone more experienced take look at it and tell me please what is wrong.
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    Context ctx;

  BackGround(Context  context)
    {
        this.ctx=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[0];
        String password = params[1];

        String data = "";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://webserver.xy/login_wellness.php");
            String urlParams = "email=" + name + "&password=" + password;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while ((tmp = is.read()) != -1) {
                data += (char) tmp;
            }
            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exceptionn: " + e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
    if(result.equals("success"))

    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"onpost excute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
       // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);  
    }

    Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: do check the result from toast..it is properly display like "success"?

Comment: BackGround Class is in activity or separate JAVA class

Comment: @Vijaykumar yes i receive the success message.

Comment: @AbdulKawee the BackGround class is located outside of the activity in a separate JAVA class.

Comment: You use separate class you must pass the intent via parameter.

Comment: have you tried intend.addFlags , which you have commented.?

Comment: Can you give more information.. Is the toast showing. Is ctx null? is the second toast showing. Who is calling this asynctask

Comment: @skynet try below i am posting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using separate class,you just pass the class via constructor.

For example,

**Your Async class :**

**your constructor :**

```
BackGround(Context  context,Class mIntentclass) {
    this.ctx=context;
    this.mIntentclass = mIntentclass;

}
```

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

```
    if(result.equals("success")) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx,"onpost excute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,mIntentclass.class);
    ctx.startActivity(intent);  

}
   Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Your Need class :**

you just call where you want it?

like

```
BackGround background = new BackGround(context,MainActivity);
```

Hope its help u!

Comment: The problem is that compare of string result it's not compared with the word "success".
The code is jumping directly to else not testing if condition.

`if( result.equals("success"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"onpost excute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);

    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Valoare lui result in else"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }`

Comment: where you store server response  String data = "" this one right or not?

Comment: This was the problem, now it's working fine as globally!
Thanks a lot for all your help man, cheers for that!
:)

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor as

```
BackGround(Context  context)
{
    this.ctx=context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

And then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have previously done that but it's not working.
The toast from inside of the if block 
    
`if(result.equals("success"))

    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"onpost excute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
       // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);  
    }`
it's not executed

Comment: It should have worked, from where are you calling this class , or is ctx null or not?

Comment: have you tried changing constructor?? with getApplicationContext()

Comment: The CTX value it's not null, and inside constructor i have tried to include getAplicationContext() and also it's not working, it's the same problem - it's not enter on if block but the toast outside the if block it's working fine displaying successful message.